# Different design desktop/mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile

I hope there is an answer for this question. 
I'm not good at codeing and I hope someone will understand my question.

Is there any way to have 2 different designs.. 
I have a design for a desktop/ipad and one for mobile devices.
The one for the mobile device is more like the design of an application.
So what I want now is if my javascript code find out that the website is opened on a mobile device, the website turn into the version for the mobile device.

For example: 
The desktop/ipad version is the index.html and the mobile version is the mobile.html

is there a way to make a javascript code to go to the mobile version if

if(!is_mobile) {
    (function(XXXXX) {
        XXXXXX
}

Answer (score 0):

The following javascript code will be useful:

```
function adjustStyle() {
    var width = 0;

    //getting width of webpage
    if (window.innerHeight) {
        width = window.innerWidth
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if (document.body) {
        width = document.body.clientWidth;
    }

    //loading css if width less than 600. Make sure your link tag has id  "myCSS"
    if (width < 600) {
        document.getElementById("myCSS").setAttribute("href", "css/mobile.css")
    } else {
        document.getElementById("myCSS").setAttribute("href", "css/desktop.css")
    }
}

//calling the function
window.onresize = function () {
    adjustStyle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use a responsive html + css. That would automatically restyle the page based on the device type or screen size.
But if you prefer to do it this way, you can do it like this:

In the header of index.html (before any styles or scripts) you can filter the device that is currently opening the page and forward the user to the mobile html (if he's coming from a mobile device).

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
   window.location.href = 'mobile.html';
}
</script>
```

Hope it helps.